# Create form with two choices fileds

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want create two choces field like that, because if i generate form i have problem with __toString() method, because i need to fields passed to the function.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/transport", name="transportAction")
 * @Template("CoreBundle:Goods:transport.html.twig")
 */
public function transportAction()
{
    $storageItems = new StorageItems();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($storageItems)
        ->add('storageitems_to_deliveries', 'entity', [
            'class' => 'ModelBundle:Deliveries',
            'choices' => $storageItems->getStorageitemsToDeliveries()
        ])
        ->add('storageitems_to_strorage', 'entity', [
            'class' => 'ModelBundle:Storages',
            'choices' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ModelBundle:Storages')->findAll(),
            //'property'=> 'secondStorage'
        ])
        ->getForm();

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

In result i have error

> Warning: Illegal offset type

What i do wrong? How fixed it?

P.S

```
class Deliveries
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Items", inversedBy="items_to_deliveries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="items_to_deliveries_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $deliveries_to_items;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Workers", inversedBy="workers_to_deliveries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="workers_to_deliveries_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $deliveries_to_workers;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StorageItems", mappedBy="storageitems_to_deliveries", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $deliveries_to_storageitems;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->deliveries_to_storageitems = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->deliveries_to_workers;
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a nice user name, sounds like you're here to stay...

Comment: LOL didn't pay attention to that. Funny username indeed :D

Answer (score 2):

I see three issues here (2 major, 1 minor):

- `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ModelBundle:Deliveries')`

This will return an `array` of `Deliveries` objects. Symfony2 has no way of determining the textual representation needed for label, **unless** you implement `__toString()` (**major**)

In addition, `array` will be numerically indexed. The values for form elements will be `0`, `1`, etc... This can cause some inexplicable behaviors and headaches along the way. You should consider returning array which uses object ID as it's key. (**minor issue**)

- `'data' => ''`

Hit this wall a few times. `data` attribute will override everything and anything, be it a default entity member value or the value that came from `Request`. Be careful when using it ;) (**major**)

Hope this helps...

Comment: i can't do it (
My strucrute
http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=473b39d46eb249596068c0284058ff76
Can you help me?

Comment: It *might* work, but that's not the way it is *supposed* to be used. You should really use it as official documentation tells...